# What's the proper way to add selected and related attributes to inputs?

Tags: html

What is the proper way (standards compliant) way to add `selected`, `disabled` and similar attributes to `<input>` elements in HTML?

I have seen:

```
<input type="text" disabled>

<input type="text" disabled="disabled">

<input type="text" disabled="yes">
```

As far as I can tell, they all work, regardless of what the attribute's value is.
What is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`disabled` is a boolean attribute.

`disabled="disabled"` is the correct form; `disabled` alone is shorthand allowed in HTML.

From [On SGML and HTML:](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.3.4.2)

> Boolean attributes may legally take a single value: the name of the attribute itself (e.g., selected="selected").
>
> In HTML, boolean attributes may appear in minimized form -- the attribute's value appears alone in the element's start tag. Thus, selected may be set by writing:
>
> ```
> <OPTION selected>
> ```
>
> instead of:
>
> ```
> <OPTION selected="selected">
> ```
>
> Authors should be aware that many user
> agents only recognize the minimized
> form of boolean attributes and not the
> full form.

Comment: It seems like regardless of what I use, even "falsy" values like `disabled=""`, `disabled=false`, `disabled=0` the result is still the same

Comment: Also: "Authors should be aware that many user agents only recognize the minimized form of boolean attributes and not the full form." So it seems like a recommendation to use `disabled` rather than `disabled="disabled"`?

Comment: @pessi yes, true. Although I know of no browser that can't deal with `disabled="disabled"`.

Comment: @pessi regarding the falsy values, `disabled=""` *should* be false in my understanding but it's possible that introducing the attribute at all already makes it true.

Comment: @pessi what I said in my last comment seems to be true. From the link: `Their appearance in the start tag of an element implies that the value of the attribute is "true". Their absence implies a value of "false".`