# What's the correct way to disable a button with html?

Tags: html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the proper way to add selected and related attributes to inputs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3894518/whats-the-proper-way-to-add-selected-and-related-attributes-to-inputs)
>   [Correct value for disabled attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6961526/correct-value-for-disabled-attribute)

I have the following:

```
    <button id="refreshLink" class="blue" type="button" title="Refresh Topic Grid"
        data-entity="Topic"
        data-href="/Admin/Contents/Reference">
        <span class="center-icon sprite-arrow-circle"></span></button>
```

I saw lots of different ways to make this disabled.

```
disabled=true
disabled=disabled
disabled
```

Which is the correct way to do this? I am getting confused.

Comment: which version of Html? I think html5 can have a different syntax. And doesn't your prefered web editor suggest you the correct syntax (I use Visual studio, and it's one of its feature).

Comment: Also [Correct value for disabled attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6961526)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second two (`disabled=disabled` and `disabled`) are both correct. You can choose which one to use based on personal preference. The `disabled` attribute is a Boolean attribute, which [can not contain the value `true` (although it will still work)](http://developers.whatwg.org/common-microsyntaxes.html#boolean-attribute).

Answer (score 0):

disabled="disabled" and `disabled` are the same thing.

Both are well understood by browsers.

I've never seen `disabled=true`, so consider that it's probably not a good practice.

EDITED.

Fore information, W3C recomendations is :

```
<button disabled>
```

Source: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.12.1

( bad link keep for history: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_disabled.asp )

Comment: `disabled=true ` is invalid syntax - check a validator.

Comment: Sorry. I make a mistake between <button disabled="disabled"> and disabled="true".

Comment: [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com) is not the W3C, and is usually full of [errors](http://w3fools.com/)!

Comment: @Inkbug You're right (again). 2 mistakes on the same comment. -_-' I've replace a w3scools link by the w3c one.

Comment: That's better. Removed my down vote.

Answer (score 0):

```
disabled=disabled
```

Is the Correct function as per my understanding

if you give disabled=xxx i.e)it also works but `disabled=disabled` is correct one